# Dynamically call overload methods of subclass

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, cil

I'm writing a game server in C# and now I have a problem of calling appropriate method handling each message by its type correctly. My current solution illustrated in this simple code:

```
public class DynamicBase
{
    public int Method(Abc abc) => 2;
    public virtual void Run()
    {
        IAbc abc = new Abc();
        Console.WriteLine(Method((dynamic)abc)); // print 2
        IAbc aha = new Aha();
        // expecting print 3
        Console.WriteLine(Method((dynamic)aha)); //Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
    }
}
public class DynamicSub : DynamicBase
{
    public int Method(Aha a) => 3;
}
public class Abc : IAbc { }
public class Aha : IAbc { }
public interface IAbc { }
//In Main(): new DynamicSub().Run();
```

The exception for `Method((dynamic)aha)` is due to the runtime only check for `Method` overloads of `DynamicBase` and its base class. If I want it to call `Method` in `DynamicSub` then I need to override the `Run` with exact the same code in base class.

So, how can I achieve this behavior without an override?

If not, how can I dynamically emit an override of `Run` for the sub class by programmatically copying the virtual method (I mean IL code)? So that my user (of my lib) doesn't have to copy the `Run` method to sub class by herself.

Comment: What should be called for `Console.WriteLine(Method((dynamic)aha));` if some inheritor `DynamicSub2` will not have `Method(Aha a)`?

Comment: You are trying to achieve very strange behavior. You should never try to call derived class methods inside base class. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @GuruStron A RuntimeBinderException is thrown. If I want to silent the exception then I will have `Method(object o)`

Comment: @VladaxLe Say I'm having a `PeerBase` class that handle requests from client. It deserializes incoming requests to POCOs. Each POCO will be handled differently by an appropriate `Method` which acts as an interface for subclasses

Comment: C# and other OOP languages resolve methods at compile time or run time.
Virtual methods are resolved at run time, overload methods are resolved at compile time.

My case here is I'm trying to call overload methods, they are resolved at compile time so I made it resolved at run time by forcing `this` as `dynamic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Console.WriteLine(Method((dynamic)aha));
```

That resolves `Method` at compile time, which indeed will be only `DynamicBase.Method`.

What you want is dynamically resolve `Method` which means reference on which you call the method must be `dynamic`:

```
Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)this).Method((dynamic)aha));
```

Note that most likely there is more type-safe solution to whatever you trying to achieve. If you are working hard to circumvent all type safety of C# you may want look into more dynamic  languages - JavaScript with NodeJS is a good choice.

Comment: "there is more type-safe solution". I did maintain a Dictionary of delegates for each object type in parameter before but it was much slower than dynamic. I also have a `Method(Object obj)` to handle all param types that I don't know so avoid handling `RuntimeBinderException` impact performance a lots.